# Fatal Exception with phonegap barcode scanner plugin

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am receiving the following error in eclipse when I click my QR Code button:

```
09-19 17:47:03.703: E/AndroidRuntime(21726): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-19 17:47:03.703: E/AndroidRuntime(21726): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to         
instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.knotis.knotisdroidapp/com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity}:     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity
09-19 17:47:03.703: E/AndroidRuntime(21726):    at   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
09-19 17:47:03.703: E/AndroidRuntime(21726):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2229)
09-19 17:47:03.703: E/AndroidRuntime(21726):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
09-19 17:47:03.703: E/AndroidRuntime(21726):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1261)
09-19 17:47:03.703: E/AndroidRuntime(21726):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-19 17:47:03.703: E/AndroidRuntime(21726):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
09-19 17:47:03.703: E/AndroidRuntime(21726):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4944)
09-19 17:47:03.703: E/AndroidRuntime(21726):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-19 17:47:03.703: E/AndroidRuntime(21726):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-19 17:47:03.703: E/AndroidRuntime(21726):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-19 17:47:03.703: E/AndroidRuntime(21726):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-19 17:47:03.703: E/AndroidRuntime(21726):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-19 17:47:03.703: E/AndroidRuntime(21726): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity
09-19 17:47:03.703: E/AndroidRuntime(21726):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
09-19 17:47:03.703: E/AndroidRuntime(21726):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
09-19 17:47:03.703: E/AndroidRuntime(21726):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
09-19 17:47:03.703: E/AndroidRuntime(21726):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1039)
09-19 17:47:03.703: E/AndroidRuntime(21726):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2101)
09-19 17:47:03.703: E/AndroidRuntime(21726):    ... 11 more
```

Here is my manifest file. Im pretty sure it has to do with how my activity is named..

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.knotis.knotisdroidapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
    <supports-screens 
    android:largeScreens="true" 
    android:normalScreens="true" 
    android:smallScreens="true" 
    android:resizeable="true" 
    android:anyDensity="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <!-- ZXing activities --> 
        <activity 
            android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity" 
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" 
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" 
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" 
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" 
            android:exported="false"> 
            <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.SCAN"/> 
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                  </intent-filter> 
                  </activity> 
        <activity 
            android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.encode.EncodeActivity" 
            android:label="@string/share_name"> 
            <intent-filter> 
                <action android:name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.ENCODE"/> 
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/> 
            </intent-filter> 
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have already double checked permissions and things like that.

Comment: if you´re using eclipse, did you add the JAR File of the Scanner to the build path?

Comment: The scanner is installed correctly. It has something to do with how the activity was named.

Comment: Did you make sure you are including the library project in your app?